# Understanding the return value of spawn

Tags: erlang, argument-passing, variable-assignment, spawn

I'm getting started with Erlang, and could use a little help understanding the different results when applying the PID returned from `spawn/3` to the `process_info/1` method.

Given this simple code where the `a/0` function is exported, which simply invokes `b/0`, which waits for a message:

```
-module(tester).
-export([a/0]).

a() ->
    b().
b() ->
    receive {Pid, test} ->
        Pid ! alrighty_then
    end.
```

...please help me understand the reason for the different output from the shell:

---

**Example 1:**

Here, `current_function` of `Pid` is shown as being `tester:b/0`:

```
Pid = spawn(tester, a, []).

process_info( Pid ).

> [{current_function,{tester,b,0}},
    {initial_call,{tester,a,0}},
    ...
```

---

**Example 2:**

Here, `current_function` of `process_info/1` is shown as being `tester:a/0`:

```
process_info( spawn(tester, a, []) ).

> [{current_function,{tester,a,0}},
    {initial_call,{tester,a,0}},
    ...
```

---

**Example 3:**

Here, `current_function` of `process_info/1` is shown as being `tester:a/0`, but the `current_function` of `Pid` is `tester:b/0`:

```
process_info( Pid = spawn(tester, a, []) ).

> [{current_function,{tester,a,0}},
    {initial_call,{tester,a,0}},
    ...

process_info( Pid ).

> [{current_function,{tester,b,0}},
    {initial_call,{tester,a,0}},
    ...
```

---

I assume there's some asynchronous code happening in the background when `spawn/3` is invoked, but how does variable assignment and argument passing work (especially in the last example) such that `Pid` gets one value, and `process_info/1` gets another?

Is there something special in Erlang that binds variable assignment in such cases, but no such binding is offered to argument passing?

---

**EDIT:**

If I use a function like this:

```
TestFunc = fun( P ) -> P ! {self(), test}, flush() end.

TestFunc( spawn(tester,a,[]) ).
```

...the message is returned properly from `tester:b/0`:

```
Shell got alrighty_then
ok
```

But if I use a function like this:

```
TestFunc2 = fun( P ) -> process_info( P ) end.

TestFunc2( spawn(tester,a,[]) ).
```

...the `process_info/1` still shows `tester:a/0`:

```
[{current_function,{tester,a,0}},
 {initial_call,{tester,a,0}},
 ...
```

Not sure what to make of all this. Perhaps I just need to accept it as being above my pay grade!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at the docs for [spawn](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#spawn-3) it says it returns the newly created Pid and places the new process in the system scheduler queue. In other words, the process gets started but the caller keeps on executing.

Erlang is different from some other languages in that you don't have to explicitly yield control, but rather you rely on the process scheduler to determine when to execute which process. In the cases where you were making an assignment to `Pid`, the scheduler had ample time to switch over to the spawned process, which subsequently made the call to `b/0`.

Comment: So "system scheduler" == "don't sweat the details". I can handle that. I did read the docs first, and that was what initially made me start thinking about this. I wondered why it is that I'm spawning `a/0` but getting the PID for `b/0`. I mean that was certainly the desired behavior, but I couldn't understand the mechanics of it. I guess Erlang just knows which PID to return in that scenario.

Comment: The Pid isn't changing - it "points" to a process which is running. As it runs, it executes different functions (in your case A, then B). `current_function` only shows you which function that process happens to be executing at the exact moment you call `process_info/1`. If you manage to look at it immediately it will be in `a/0`, but if you give it long enough it will be in `b/0`.

Comment: Ah!!! My thinking was wrong (obviously). I had it in my head that when you spawn a process (by referencing a function in `spawn/3`), that each function invoked along the way would have its own unique PID associated with it. But instead the process is broader, and may encompass the invocation of many functions, and the PID is simply a reference to the overall "process" that is occurring. If that sounds correct (though clumsily put), then I believe I'm understanding it.

Answer (score 6):

It's really quite simple. The execution of the spawned process starts with a call to a() which  at some point shortly afterwards will call b() and then just sits there and waits until it receives a specific message. In the examples where you manage to immediately call process_info on the pid, you catch it while the process is still executing a(). In the other cases, when some delay is involved, you catch it after it has called b(). What about this is confusing?